How should we flag computer generated answers?
Answers given by a now deleted user appear to have been computer generated:

The answers were wordy generalities
The user submitted 6 answers over a short period of time

How should these posts have been flagged?

I flag them and choose the last option (In need of moderator intervention) with a custom message like "Likely AI generated answer." Since we (luckily) don't have many such answers, I believe there is no need yet of a new flagging option ... :)
